# Spring Boot ErrorController logging with Logback MDC

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, logging, logback, mdc

(UPDATE: My question seems to be same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55146885/4506703), but it has no effective answer.)

I'm trying logging on Spring Boot `ErrorController`, but it's logs don't have MDC value.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/error")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    private final ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> error(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        final ServletWebRequest webRequest = new ServletWebRequest(request);
        final Throwable th = errorAttributes.getError(webRequest);

        if (th != null) {
            // **Logged without "requestId" value**
            log.error("MyErrorController", th);
        }

        return Map.of("result", "error");
    }
}
```

```java
// http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html#autoMDC
public class MDCFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
        final FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        MDC.put("requestId", requestId);

        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            MDC.remove("requestId");
        }
    }

}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<MDCFilter> mdcFilter() {
        final FilterRegistrationBean<MDCFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        bean.setFilter(new MDCFilter());
        bean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

`logback-spring.xml`:

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] requestId:%X{requestId} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

result(`requestId` value does not appear):

```
18:15:13.705 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] requestId: ERROR c.e.l.MyErrorController - MyErrorController
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occured.
...
```

[Here is complete code](https://github.com/yukihane/logging-with-mdc-demo).

I think that I need to adapt `MDCFilter` before `DispatcherServlet`, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Your code works for me 08:10:40.089 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] MY_MDC_VALUE ERROR c.e.loggingwithmdcdemo.MyController - MyController

Answer (score 3):

Remove MDC data on [`ServletRequestListener#requestDestroyed()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletrequestlistener#requestDestroyed-javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent-) instead of on `Filter`.

On  Tomcat [StandardHostValve](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.44/java/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardHostValve.java#L169-L186) fires `RequestDestroyEvent` after `ErrorController` executing.

```java
            // Look for (and render if found) an application level error page
            if (response.isErrorReportRequired()) {
                // If an error has occurred that prevents further I/O, don't waste time
                // producing an error report that will never be read
                AtomicBoolean result = new AtomicBoolean(false);
                response.getCoyoteResponse().action(ActionCode.IS_IO_ALLOWED, result);
                if (result.get()) {
                    if (t != null) {
                        throwable(request, response, t); // *ErrorController is executed*
                    } else {
                        status(request, response);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!request.isAsync() && !asyncAtStart) {
                context.fireRequestDestroyEvent(request.getRequest()); // *RequestDestroyEvent is fired*
            }
```

So, implement following:

```java
public class MDCClearListener implements ServletRequestListener {

    @Override
    public void requestDestroyed(final ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        MDC.remove("requestId");
    }
}
```

```java
    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<MDCClearListener> mdcClearListener() {
        final ServletListenerRegistrationBean<MDCClearListener> bean = new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>();
        bean.setListener(new MDCClearListener());
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }
```

(Concrete code exists on [`solution` branch](https://github.com/yukihane/logging-with-mdc-demo/tree/solution).)

---

#### About related question's answer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66913638/4506703) does not fit for me. Because:

The first way does not use `ErrorController` but `@ExceptionHandler`, so cannot catch exceptions thrown by Spring Security `Filter`.
(Try [`answer/exceptionhandler-with-springsecurity` branch](https://github.com/yukihane/logging-with-mdc-demo/tree/answer/exceptionhandler-with-springsecurity) code.)

The second way puts UUID on interceptor, so logged diffrent requestId between `MyController` and `MyErrorController`. This is not "request" id.
(Try [`answer/interceptor` branch](https://github.com/yukihane/logging-with-mdc-demo/tree/answer/interceptor) code.)

Answer (score 0):

Everything works as expected.

This is the logged line:

```
08:19:34.204 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] MY_MDC_VALUE DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Failed to complete request: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occured.
```

What you've posted is the log from MyErroController

```
08:19:34.209 [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  ERROR c.e.l.MyErrorController - MyErrorController
```

And as you do call

```
MDC.clear();
```

the MDC is empty when this log statement is executed.

Comment: Yes, my current implementation clears MDC before logging, so it should be modified. However I don't know how to do...

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain well enough. In actually `MY_MDC` is request-scoped information, so I followed [Example 7.5](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html).

Comment: I don't understand your question?